# HTML текст справа от текста

Tags: html, css

Допустим у меня слева располагается логотип+заголовочный текст. Справа на ток же строке хочу написать телефон и адрес. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<nav>
    <div class="left">
        <img src="#" alt="LOGO">
        <h1>Brand</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>phone</p>
        <p>adress</p>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.device {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="">
    <div class="device">lorem ipsum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="phone">
    <p>+88007007080</p>
    <p>mail@gmail.com</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

если правильно понял

```css
ul.hr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul.hr li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="hr">
    <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/NASA_logo.svg/200px-NASA_logo.svg.png"></li>
    <li>Номер телефона и адресс</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Даже с текущей вёрсткой, левый и правый блоки должны разойтись по сторонам.
Если этого по какой-то причине не произошло, попробуйте явно указать `flex-direction`:

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Если же вы хотели чтобы правый блок был сразу после левого, то удалите `justify-content`.

Если ничего из этого не дало ответ на ваш вопрос, то сформулируйте его по-другому потому что не совсем понятно что вы ожидаете увидеть, и что получается.